# Does deleting index in kibana, deletes same index in elastic search too?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i am new to ELK stack internals,

So I want to completely delete the index from Elastic search also, So can this be achieved just from Kibana UI same delete option or should i execute XDELETE from elastic search

Please confirm with your experiences

Yesterday i tried to delete index in kibana ui on dustbin icon, but still i can see good health in elastic search end, thats why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the dustbin icon you refer to is on the **Management** > **Index patterns** page. This will only delete the index pattern in Kibana, and will have no effect on the index.

To delete the actual index via Kibana, Use the **Dev Tools** tab and run `DELETE myindex`

Comment: **Management** > **Elasticsearch** > **Index Management** > **Manage index** > **Delete index** appears to do the same thing as **Dev Tools** > **Console** > `DELETE myindex`. I haven't tested this though.